# Difference of two timedelta objects, with timezones

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, timedelta, tzinfo

I would like to calculate how many hours there are in a date interval: for example "2014.03.29-30" should give 47, because of the daylight savings.

My method is making two datetime objects, in the example the following:

```
datetime.datetime(2014, 3, 29, 0, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Budapest' LMT+1:16:00 STD>)
datetime.datetime(2014, 3, 30, 23, 59, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Budapest' LMT+1:16:00 STD>)
return (date2-date1) + timedelta(minutes=1)
```

However, it gives "2 days, 0:00:00", which is not correct. How could I make a timedelta object which takes timezones and dst into account? Also, if there's a simpler solution for the whole problem, I'm open to it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before 1901-12-13 20:45:52 UTC, the `'Europe/Budapest'` timezone was LMT+1:16:00 STD.
Currently, as of 2016-05-05, the `'Europe/Budapest'` timezone is CET+2:00:00 DST.

If you use pytz's [`localize` method](http://pythonhosted.org/pytz/#localized-times-and-date-arithmetic), then pytz will choose the timezone (utcoffset and dstoffset) for `'Europe/Budapest'` which is appropriate for the given naive datetime:

```
import datetime as DT
import pytz

tzone = pytz.timezone('Europe/Budapest')
date1 = tzone.localize(DT.datetime(2014, 3, 29, 0, 0), is_dst=None)
# datetime.datetime(2014, 3, 29, 0, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Budapest' CET+1:00:00 STD>)
```

In contrast, if you supply `tzinfo=tzone` directly to `datetime.datetime`, as in:

```
wrong_date1 = datetime.datetime(2014, 3, 29, 0, 0, tzinfo=tzone)
# datetime.datetime(2014, 3, 29, 0, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Budapest' LMT+1:16:00 STD>)
```

then the `datetime.datetime` **incorrectly chooses the very first timezone** associated with `'Europe/Budapest'` *regardless of whether or not that was the timezone in effect on 2014-3-29*.

Therefore, when using pytz, always use `tzone.localize` to make naive datetimes timezone-aware:

```
import datetime as DT
import pytz
tzone = pytz.timezone('Europe/Budapest')
date1 = tzone.localize(DT.datetime(2014, 3, 29, 0, 0), is_dst=None)
date2 = tzone.localize(DT.datetime(2014, 3, 30, 23, 59), is_dst=None)
print(((date2-date1) + DT.timedelta(minutes=1)).total_seconds()/3600.)
# 47.0
```

[Do not use `tzinfo=tzone`](http://pythonhosted.org/pytz/#localized-times-and-date-arithmetic) unless `tzone` is `pytz.utc` (or a timezone which is alway the same throughout its history.)

---

*Where did the date `1901-12-13 20:45:52 UTC` come from?*

You can peek at a pytz timezone's utc transition times (and associated transition info) using its `tzone._utc_transition_times` and `tzone._transition_info` private attributes:

```
In [43]: [(utcdate, utcoffset, dstoffset, tzabbrev) for utcdate, (utcoffset, dstoffset, tzabbrev) in zip(tzone._utc_transition_times, tzone._transition_info)][:2]
Out[43]: 
[(datetime.datetime(1, 1, 1, 0, 0),
  datetime.timedelta(0, 4560),
  datetime.timedelta(0),
  'LMT'),
 (datetime.datetime(1901, 12, 13, 20, 45, 52),
  datetime.timedelta(0, 3600),
  datetime.timedelta(0),
  'CET')]
```

This shows that from the date `1-1-1 UTC` to `1901-12-13 20:45:52 UTC` the timezone abbreviation was `LMT` and the utcoffset was 4560 seconds, which equals 1 hour and 16 minutes:

```
In [47]: print(DT.timedelta(0, 4560))
1:16:00
```

Hence the first timezone associated with `'Europe/Budapest'` is `LMT+1:16:00 STD`.

Comment: Thank you! One last thing: what does the `is_dst=None` part do? I accidentally skipped it, but it works as it should, too.

Comment: `is_dst=None` tells `tzone.localize` to raise an `AmbiguousTimeError` for ambiguous times when Daylight Savings Time is ending -- "falling back" causes the same naive time to occur twice. Otherwise it does what is appropriate. It is used out of "an abundance of caution", as a good general habit, even though it has no effect here. By default, `is_dst=False`, which means `tzone.localize` will resolve ambiguous times by *assuming* that the naive datetime refers to the datetime when Daylight Savings Time is not in effect.

Comment: `is_dst=None` may also raise a `NonExistentTimeError` when Daylight Savings Time is starting. For example, if `pacific = pytz.timezone('US/Pacific')`, `date = DT.datetime(2008, 3, 9, 2, 0, 0)`, then `pacific.localize(date, is_dst=None)` raises `NonExistentTimeError`, even though `pacific.normalize(pacific.localize(date, is_dst=True))` (or the same with `is_dst=False`) returns a date (1 o'clock or 3 o'clock, but never 2 o'clock).

Comment: Thanks! Great tip not to use the conventional  `datetime.datetime(2014, 3, 29, 0, 0, tzinfo=tzone)`  An absolute lifesaver!